# How to trigger radio button in angular 12

Tags: typescript, angular9, angular12

I am trying to trigger the radio button in angular 12 but it is not working. If i click the button depends on the text i want to checked the radio button.

```
If i click beef button, beef radio button should be checked. 
If i click Lamb button, Lamb radio button should be checked. 
If i click Fish button, Fish radio button should be checked.
```

radios.component.html:

```
<input type="radio" name="food" value="beef" [(ngModel)]="myFood" /> Beef
<input type="radio" name="food" value="lamb" [(ngModel)]="myFood" /> Lamb
<input type="radio" name="food" value="fish" [(ngModel)]="myFood" /> Fish

<br /><br />

<button (click)="checkit('beef')">Beef</button>
<button (click)="checkit('lamb')">Lamb</button>
<button (click)="checkit('fish')">Fish</button>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rktjxe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradios%2Fradios.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, your texts just come after the input, but there is nothing that defines that a text really *belong* to its corresponding input. An easy way to fix this is to declare your texts (Beef, Lamb, Fish) as label for their input. Just add a label and reference the `id` of each input with the `for`attribute.

```html
<input type="radio" id="beef" name="beef" value="beef" [(ngModel)]="myFood">
<label for="beef">Beef</label>

<input type="radio" id="lamb" name="lamb" value="lamb" [(ngModel)]="myFood">
<label for="lamb">Lamb</label>

<input type="radio" id="fish" name="fish" value="fish" [(ngModel)]="myFood">
<label for="fish">Fish</label>
```

In order to trigger the radio buttons via normal buttons, you can just set your ngModel to the corresponding value inside your `checkit()` function like that:

```
checkit(val: string) {
    this.myFood = val;
}
```

Try it out in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9fqare?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradios%2Fradios.component.ts).

Comment: Please understand my question. If i click the button only not label

Comment: @Smart Code: Sorry, I completely missed the button part in your question. Updated my answer.

Comment: can we set the myFood  value from the url? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zzqxzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradios%2Fradios.component.ts

Comment: Sure, that's possible and you're almost there. You try to get the query parameters of the active route, so you just have to make sure to pass one in the URL. Just enter the url "https://angular-ivy-zzqxzs.stackblitz.io/radios?page=fish" inside StackBlitz's embedded browser to set the selection to fish.

Comment: But please let's not discuss additional topics here in the comments. If you have further questions, please check if this might already exist on StackOverflow or open a new question if you need to.